# ¿Cómo dibujar un mapa político?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, aplicación-web

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de un mapa de mi país; vivo en Honduras, que se divide en departamentos, y cada departamento en municipios.

He visto que con Google Maps se dibujan los límites entre cada departmento,
pero no muestra en el departamento, no muestra su división en municipios.

Les pongo un ejemplo del resultado que quiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, todo lo de color son departamentos; cada color distino con su nombre es un municipio.

¿Es posible hacer esa division con Google Maps?

Comment: No me queda claro,¿para qué necesitas utilizar Google Maps en la aplicación? ¿Qué es lo que quieres resolver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> es posible hacer esa division con google maps

No, o muy difícilmente.

Necesitarás tener geometrías para las regiones (departamentos, municipios) que quieras visualizar. Aunque en GMaps veas el contorno de las divisiones administrativas, eso no significa que puedas acceder a esas geometrías de manera programática.

Si quieres dibujar un mapa político, o un [mapa coroplético](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapa_coropl%C3%A9tico), necesitarás datos para las áreas que quieras dibujar. La pregunta de "¿dónde puedo encontrar y descargar esos datos?" no tiene una respuesta sencilla, pero deberías investigar si el Instituto Geográfico Nacional de Honduras te los puede facilitar. En otro caso, puedes recurrir a datos de límites administrativos de [OpenStreetMap](http://www.osm.org), p. ej en los [extractos de MapZen](https://mapzen.com/data/borders/).

Una vez tengas los datos, sólo tienes que dibujar cada área (polígono) con un color distinto. El [tutorial de Leaflet para mapas coropléticos](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth-example.html) debería poder ayudarte.

Ten en cuenta que quizás GMaps no sea la herramienta más adecuada. Antes de "casarte" con una plataforma, te sugiero investigar si QGis, gvSIG, Leaflet o OpenLayers te pueden ser más útiles.

Comment: Si, es posible utilizando polígonos de gmaps (es decir, la herramienta te permitiría lograrlo). Un ejemplo simple de la documentación se encuentra [aquí](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple?hl=es).
Concuerdo que para ello es necesario tener la información de las divisiones a mostrar (los polígonos) e implementarlo. Y que dependiendo el objetivo, podría ser más útil utilizar alguna otra herramienta.

Comment: muchas gracias a todos !!! encontre  la solucion no del todo pero me servio. probe con leafletjs js   es muy bueno tambien u encontre los limites de cada deparmento en mapzen -> https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts/ usando geoJson